# NSS on FireFox on Android

Tags: firefox-addon, ctypes, nss

I was trying to get the default cert DB of firefox on android using ctypes and NSS(`CERT_GetDefaultCertDB`). But I was not able to open NSS on FF android. Is NSS available on FireFox on Android?

I tried the follwing:

```
   var ds = Services.dirsvc.get("GreD", Components.interfaces.nsILocalFile); 
   var libName = ctypes.libraryName("nss3"); 
   ds.append(libName); 

   var nsslib = ctypes.open(ds.path); // FAILS TO OPEN
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you have to initialize NSS, indirectly through the initialization of PSM (Personal Security Manager)

```
Components.classes["@mozilla.org/psm;1"].getService(Components.interfaces.nsISupports);
```

Also you should first `try` to open NSS library without applying a path, and if you `catch` an exception then try again with "GreD".